# How to find the order of an element and the index

Tags: abstract-algebra

The dihedral group of order $2n$ is given by:
$$D_n = \{ \sigma^i\rho^j : i, j, \in \mathbb{Z}, \sigma^n = 1, \rho^2 = 1, \sigma\rho = \rho\sigma^{-1}\}.$$

If $G = D_5$ and $a = \sigma^2$, find $|a|$ and $[G: \langle a \rangle]$

I have that $|G| = 2(5) = 10$. I think that $\sigma^2 = 1$ (using the definition) but I get very confused when $\sigma$, $\rho$ start getting thrown in.

Comment: $\rho^2 = 1$. $\sigma$ is the other generator, of order 5. So... what order has $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Are you sure you wnat $\sigma^n = 1$ and $\rho^2 = 1$? Typically we work with $\sigma^2 = 1$ and $\rho^n = 1$. Here $\rho$ stands for "rho"-tation. Also, what have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we know where you're stuck we can help you better ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I don't believe that to be standard. Typically I have seen this problem with $\sigma$ and $\tau$, with $\tau$ in place of $\rho$ as above. That or $r$ and $s$, or $s$ and $t$.

Comment: I have defined the dihedral group as it was defined in the question. I'm not even really sure where to start though I know that the order of a is the number of times you need to compose a to get back to the identity - so I guess since a is already the identity, using the definition, the order of a is 1?

Comment: $a$ is not already the identity, not as written.

Comment: It would be a rather dull question if $a$ were the identity, so the index equal to $\vert G \vert = 10$.